# Restkit 0.2 returning RKMappingSourceObject type Objects for one-to-many type relationship

Tags: objective-c, core-data, restkit, restkit-0.20

I am trying to map a JSON Array in my application.The issue that I am facing is that instead of getting objects of type NSString, I am getting objects of type RKMappingSourceObject.

Response is of the form

```
{
         message =     {
            Appetite =         {
                    Breakfast = 4;
                    Dinner = 4;
                    Lunch = 4;
                };
        PainSymptom =         {
       Aching = 1;
                AtRest = 0;
                Awakes = 0;
                Burning = 0;
                Cramping = 0;
                    Location =             (
                        Head,
                        "Right Upper Leg",
                        "Left Upper Leg",
                        "Left Ankle/Foot",
                        "Right Ankle/Foot",
                        "Mid Back",
                        "Upper Back",
                        Tailbone
                    );
                };
        }
}
```

My Core Data classes are :

DTAttribute.h

```
@interface DTAttribute : NSManagedObject

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString * attribute;
@property (nonatomic, strong) DTPainSymptom *painSymptom;

@end
```

DTAttribute.m

```
@implementation DTAttribute

@dynamic attribute;
@dynamic painSymptom;

@end
```

DTPainSymptom.h

```
@interface DTPainSymptom : NSManagedObject

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber * aching;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber * atRest;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber * awakes;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber * burning;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber * cramping;
@property (nonatomic, retain) DTMyDay *myDay;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSSet *painLocations;
@end

@interface DTPainSymptom (CoreDataGeneratedAccessors)

- (void)addPainLocationsObject:(DTAttribute *)value;
- (void)removePainLocationsObject:(DTAttribute *)value;
- (void)addPainLocations:(NSSet *)values;
- (void)removePainLocations:(NSSet *)values;

@end
```

DTPainSymptom.m

```
@implementation DTPainSymptom

@dynamic aching;
@dynamic atRest;
@dynamic awakes;
@dynamic burning;
@dynamic cramping;
@dynamic myDay;
@dynamic painLocations;

@end
```

DTMyDay.h

```
@interface DTMyDay : NSManagedObject

@property (nonatomic, retain) DTPainSymptom *painSymptom;

@end
```

DTMyDay.m

```
@implementation DTMyDay

@dynamic painSymptom;

@end
```

Mappings:

@implementation DTMyDay (Mapping)

```
+ (id) mapping {
  RKEntityMapping* myDayMapping = [RKEntityMapping mappingForEntityForName:NSStringFromClass([DTMyDay class]) inManagedObjectStore:[[RKObjectManager sharedManager] managedObjectStore]];

  RKEntityMapping* attributeMapping = [RKEntityMapping mappingForEntityForName:NSStringFromClass([DTAttribute class]) inManagedObjectStore:[[RKObjectManager sharedManager] managedObjectStore]];
  [attributeMapping addPropertyMapping:[RKAttributeMapping attributeMappingFromKeyPath:nil toKeyPath:@"attribute"]];

  //Pain Symptom
  RKEntityMapping* painSymptomMapping = [RKEntityMapping mappingForEntityForName:NSStringFromClass([DTPainSymptom class]) inManagedObjectStore:[[RKObjectManager sharedManager] managedObjectStore]];
  [painSymptomMapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:@{
                                                           @"Awakes": @"awakes",
                                                           @"AtRest": @"atRest",
                                                           @"Burning": @"burning",
                                                           @"Cramping": @"cramping",
                                                           @"Aching": @"aching",
                                                           }];
  [painSymptomMapping addPropertyMapping:[RKRelationshipMapping relationshipMappingFromKeyPath:@"Location"
                                                                                     toKeyPath:@"painLocations"
                                                                                   withMapping:attributeMapping]];


  [myDayMapping addPropertyMapping:[RKRelationshipMapping relationshipMappingFromKeyPath:@"message.PainSymptom"
                                                                               toKeyPath:@"painSymptom"
                                                                             withMapping:painSymptomMapping]];

  NSDateFormatter* dateFormatter = [NSDateFormatter new];
  [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd"];
  myDayMapping.dateFormatters = [NSArray arrayWithObject: dateFormatter];
  return myDayMapping;
}


+ (id)responseDescriptor:(NSString *)pathPattern {
  RKResponseDescriptor *responseDescriptor = [RKResponseDescriptor responseDescriptorWithMapping:[self mapping] pathPattern:pathPattern keyPath:nil statusCodes:RKStatusCodeIndexSetForClass(RKStatusCodeClassSuccessful)];
  return responseDescriptor;
}

@end
```

The issue here is that the array of values corresponding to `message.PainSymptom.Location` are not mapped properly. I am getting an array of DTAttribute type object corresponding to `painLocations` in `DTMyDay` class. However when I am trying to access attribute property of each DTAttribute class in painLocations array , I am getting object of type `RkMappingSourceObject` instead of type `NSString`.

I am sorry for this huge wall of code but right now I really have no idea what to do.

[image]

This causes me a problem because I am sending dtAttribute.attribute to a method, it is returning me NSNotFound since The object passed is of type RKMappingSourceObject:

```
#define BODY_PARTS_NAMES @"Head", @"Right Shoulder", @"Neck", @"Left Shoulder", @"Right Chest", @"Left Chest", @"Right Arm", nil

- (BodyPart)bodyPartStringToEnum:(NSString *)strVal
{
    NSArray *bodyPartsArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:BODY_PARTS_NAMES];
    NSUInteger index = [bodyPartsArray indexOfObject:strVal];

    return index;
}
```

Comment: What problem does the `RKMappingSourceObject` proxy class cause you? It just forwards all method calls to the true object. Are you trying to use the string description somewhere (that will look strange compared to what you expect)?

Comment: I have a function which takes a NSString argument and returns me some value. When I am sending dtAttribute.attribute to it, it is returning me NSNotFound since The object passed is of type RKMappingSourceObject.

Comment: Can you add the code for that method to your question and we'll look at fixing it?

Comment: #define BODY_PARTS_NAMES @"Head",@"Right Shoulder", @"Neck", @"Left Shoulder",@"Right Chest",@"Left Chest",@"Right Arm", nil







+ (BodyPart) bodyPartStringToEnum:(NSString*)strVal
{
  NSArray *bodyPartsArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:BODY_PARTS_NAMES];
  NSUInteger index = [bodyPartsArray indexOfObject:strVal];
  return index;
}

However if do [dtAttribute.attribute mutableCopy] then everything works fine.

Answer (score 0):

`RKMappingSourceObject` is a proxy object used inside RestKit to deal with introspection issues and metadata during the mapping process. As it is a proxy and forwards all method calls it is simply returned at the end of the mapping. Usually this doesn't cause issues.

I didn't expect it to cause issues based on your code, but obviously something in the compare method doesn't work. `RKMappingSourceObject` should forward both the `class` request and 'normal' method calls...

`RKMappingSourceObject` has an `object` method, the question is how to know that you should call it (because the class should be returned as some subclass of `NSString`). I'd look at a nasty thing like:

```
- (BodyPart)bodyPartStringToEnum:(NSString *)strVal
{
    if ([strVal respondsToSelector:@selector(object)]) {
        strVal = [strVal object];
    }

    NSArray *bodyPartsArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:BODY_PARTS_NAMES];
    NSUInteger index = [bodyPartsArray indexOfObject:strVal];

    return index;
}
```

which I don't like but hopefully will work and be compatible with potential changes to (removal of) the proxy object in future. Alternately, debug to determine why the compare fails and look at changing the proxy implementation.

Comment: I thought of your workaround and right now I am doing like this only. But I am facing issue at other place in the code where I have filter the painSymptom.painLocations(NSSet of DTAttribute) set using NSPredicate on value attribute. It is not able to filter that set.

Comment: So you could move that code into a custom accessor method implementation (so it is always used to access the `object` from the proxy). I'm interested to know why the proxy isn't working though, debugging is the best way forwards probably. There may be an alternative using `copy` to create a new string from the proxy (probably in the managed object subclass).

Answer (score 0):

Another way of converting `RKMappingSourceObject` to `NSString`:

```
NSString *realString = [NSString stringWithString:stringProxy];
```

where `stringProxy` is an instance of `RKMappingSourceObject`.